# Angular Dart: matching rules for route path - implicit suffix wildcard?

Tags: dart, angular-routing, angular-dart

Consider (excerpt from the [AngularDart tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki)):

```dart
router.root
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'add',
      path: '/add',
      enter: view('view/addRecipe.html'))
```

How is a URL matched with such a path? Is there an implicit wildcard suffix like `/add/*` or maybe `/add*`? If so, how can I make `/add` match exactly `/add` to avoid conflicts with, say,  `/address`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, [`UrlTemplate`](https://github.com/dart-lang/route/blob/experimental_hierarchical/lib/url_template.dart) does a naive prefix match, so `/add` will match `/address`.

If you are worried about conflicts between two routes where path of one happens to be a prefix of another, then the correct approach is to put the most specific path first. For example:

```dart
router.root
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'address',
      path: '/address',
      enter: view('view/address.html'))
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'add',
      path: '/add',
      enter: view('view/addRecipe.html'))
```

Router matches routes in the order they are specified, so it will pick the first that matches.  This way `/address` will always match `address` route and `/add` will always match `add` route.

If you are worried about unintended matches of `/addFoo` to `/add`, at the moment I'm afraid there's no easy way to ensure that. If you feel strongly about it please [file a feature request](https://github.com/angular/route.dart/issues/new) against the route_hierarchical package.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the source code (client.dart in route_hierarchial package, which in turn is used by AngularDart) you will notice that path is used as a key into a map. This means that if your path is set to `/add` it will not match `/address`.