# How to create nice path when routing from overview page to item page in angulardart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a very common view structure with a list page and a details page. I want to create a very simple path structure like:

```
/leaderboard
/leaderboard/123
```

When setting up my routing i created:

```dart
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'leaderboard',
      path: '/leaderboard',
      enter: view('view/leaderboards.html'))
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'leaderboard',
      path: '/leaderboard/:leaderboardId',
      enter: view('view/leaderboard.html'));
```

When navigating to the `/leaderboard` everything works fine but when navigating to `/leaderboard/123`, angulardart complains that it has found multiple routes and doesn't route at all.

My current solution is to use a different path for the list page (`/leaderboards` with an 's' at the end) but that is not so nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in [this answer of *Angular Dart: matching rules for route path - implicit suffix wildcard?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482971/634863) :

> If you are worried about conflicts between two routes where path of one happens to be a prefix of another, then the correct approach is to put the most specific path first.

You can also consider using [hierarchical routes](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html#routes-are-hierarchical).

Side note : it's recommended to have unique route names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what i had to do is to but the /leaderboard/123 route first so that it generates a match. As pointed out in your link the path is matched naively as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but I'm always nervous about using ordering to make the routes work correctly. I would recommend doing something like this:

```dart
..addRoute(
    name: 'leaderboard',
    path: '/leaderboard/all',
    enter: view('view/leaderboards.html'))
..addRoute(
    name: 'leaderboard',
    path: '/leaderboard/:leaderboardId',
    enter: view('view/leaderboard.html'));
```

Making the path something like 'leaderboard/all' (or something like that) makes it a little bit more robust, I believe.

Comment: Yes i agree with your assumption. It is scary. Especially considering that angulardart logs that it has found two matching routes. Using a "/all" or "/list" path segment is okay but doesn't comply with the idea of uniform resource id.